# Git and Github showing different branches in repository

Tags: git, github

I just merged a pull request on branch `ticket-1` into my `main` branch and deleted the `ticket-1` branch. I did this through Github and now Github shows I have only one branch (`main`). After the merge, I created a new branch from the `main` branch called `ticket-3` using the GitBash command `git checkout -b ticket-3`.

After that, I noticed the code in my VScode reverted to the original code before the pull request merge. The changes made in the pull request were not in my VScode any longer, however they show up on the main branch on Github. Also, when I ran `git branch` in my GitBash, I show that I have all three branches: `main ticket-3 ticket-3`.

Not sure what is going on here, but I'm sure there is some syncing issue I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for VSCode, whose Git support is notoriously poor. However, in speaking just in terms of Git itself:

Syncing does not happen automatically with Git. The merging of the pull request at GitHub took place *only* at GitHub; there is now a new commit at GitHub that you don't have. To get it, switch to `main` locally and `pull` (or even better, `fetch` and then `merge` from the remote tracking `origin/main`).

Note that when fetching, there is an option to prune branches that no longer exist at the remote. You might still have to delete your local `ticket-1` manually; it depends on how the GUI works.

(You should probably do that *before* creating a new branch, so that the new branch takes off from the latest state of `main`.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes that was the issue. I've just pulled the code using git pull. My code in VS code is now the updated code, however Git is still showing the three branches and Github is showing the one main branch. Can I just delete the branches in Git and just create a new `ticket-3` branch? Will I have issues if I delete the `ticket-1` branch in Git since that was part of my pull request?

Comment: Also, I can't accept the answer yet, but I will when it lets me!

Comment: First may I recommend this article I've just published for people who are getting acquainted with basic Git concepts like these? https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ — As for your question, if you have not actually committed anything to `ticket-3` you can just delete it and create it anew from `main`. If you _have_ committed to `ticket-3` but you have not pushed it, you can rebase it onto `main`. That's a good way to proceed esp if this depends on what you did in the previous ticket. :)

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check out the article! Wish my bootcamp covered more branching, pull request concepts!

Comment: I'm working on a follow up article about merges, including pull requests. Note that pull requests are not a Git feature; they perform a merge at the server side, which Git would regard as impossible.